# Probability I lost when my friend told me I lost

Tags: probability

I make a bet with a friend. There's a 1/999 chance that I will lose. I don't directly know the results of this bet so there's a 99/100 chance that he will tell the truth about the results regardless of whether he wins or loses. Suppose he tells me that I lost. What is the probability that I actually lost?

So I have:

$A$ = chances of losing $\frac{1}{1000}$;

$A^c$ = chances of winning $\frac{999}{1000}$;

$B$ = chances of him telling the truth $\frac{99}{100}$;

$B^c$ = chances of him lying $\frac{1}{100}$.

By Law of Total Probability, I should have P(A) = $\frac{1}{1000}$ $\frac{1}{1000}$ + $\frac{99}{100}$ $\frac{99}{100}$ which is .980101 but that seems incorrect. So I'm pretty sure I got something wrong except I don't know what.

Hints, clarifications, explanations would be much appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT: Also, I think there's a much more simple solution for this problem since this question is from a math competition for high school level students.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Bayes's rule:

\begin{align*}
&\,\mathbb P (\text{lost}\,|\,\text{“lost”})=\frac{\mathbb P(\text{“lost”}\,|\,\text{lost})\mathbb P(\text{lost})}{\mathbb P(\text{“lost”}\,|\,\text{lost})\mathbb P(\text{lost})+\mathbb P(\text{“lost”}\,|\,\text{won})\mathbb P(\text{won})}\\=&\,\frac{0.99\times\dfrac{1}{999}}{0.99\times\dfrac{1}{999}+0.01\times\dfrac{998}{999}}\approx0.0902.
\end{align*}

Quotation marks mean what your friend told you.

Intuitively, that your friend lied is unlikely, but that you lost is way unlikelier. Don't trust him if he tells you you lost.

Comment: +1 for the brief and yet selfexplanatory distinction lost vs "lost".

Answer (score 1):

There are four possible event combinations:

loss and lie,
loss and truth,
win and lie,
win and truth.

Combined possibility of all four is A*Bc + A*B + Ac*Bc + Ac*Bc which you will find equals one.

You should then try the next step: of the above events, which ones will have him telling you that you lost, and of *those* what proportion was he lying?

Comment: Mike You didn't really answer the question here. You should post something like this as a comment.

Comment: @mtiano I asked for hints, so that's probably what he was going for.

Comment: That is what I was going for. I though that just presenting Baye's rule wouldn't aid in understanding the problem, or why that solution works.